# php as apache input filter

Tags: php, apache

Can the php5apache_filter be used as an [input filter](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#setinputfilter)?
Haven't found much documentation for php's filter sapi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter module does register an input filter *static int php_input_filter()...*. But it doesn't do much except fetching all available post data. So I *guess* the answer is: no, you can't use it as input filter the way you want.